# Getting the error while cloning the Flutter SDK from GitHub

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-test, flutter-dependencies

Hi i getting this error while cloning the Flutter SDK from GitHub.

By firing this command in terminal on MacBook.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

Comment: Did you check your internet connection?

Comment: Yes i have an wifi with the speed of 8mbps

Comment: Its just cloned fine in my macbook.

Comment: are you using proxy? do you have firewall? can you clone any other remote git repos?